# Why typescript tuples allow array.push method?

Tags: typescript, tuples

In the following code snippet which from a TypeScript file, I have defined role to be of Tuple type, therefore only 2 values of specified type should be allowed in role array.

But I am able to push a new item, why can TS compiler not prevent it ?

```
let person: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    hobbies: string[];
    role: [number, string]      //tuple type
} = {
    name: 'stack overflow',
    age: 30,
    hobbies: ['reading', 'jogging'],
    role: [2, 'author']
};

person.role[2] = 'reader';  //not allowed, which is as expected
person.role.push('reader'); //allowed, TS compiler should prevent it
```

Comment: Because to do otherwise would break too much stuff, basically, see e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6325.

Comment: You need to use `readonly [string, string]`.

Comment: If we use `readonly` then that value cannot be changed at all. `person.role[1] = 'reader';`  fails to compile. That's not the intention. The idea is to prevent compile time issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, we need to create a generic utility type wich will create a tuple with expected length but without mutable Array.prototype methods.

Consider this:

```js
type WithoutIndex<T> = Omit<T,number>


type MutableProps = 'push' | 'splice' | 'shift' | 'unshift' | 'pop' | 'sort'

type Tuple<
    Length extends number,
    Type,
    Result extends Type[] = []
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends Length
        ? WithoutIndex<Omit<Result, MutableProps>>
        : Tuple<Length, Type, [...Result, Type]>)
```

`Tuple` calls itself until length of `Result` will be the same as provided `Length` argument.
Here you have js representation:

```js
const Tuple = (length: number, result: number[] = []) => {
    if (length === result.length) {
        return result
    }
    return tuple(length, [...result, 1])
}
```

`WithoutIndex` just forbids using any numeric indexes which are not exist in tuple.

Lets try if it works:

```js
type WithoutIndex<T> = Omit<T, number>

type MutableProps = 'push' | 'splice' | 'shift' | 'unshift' | 'pop' | 'sort'

type Tuple<
    Length extends number,
    Type,
    Result extends Type[] = []
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends Length
        ? WithoutIndex<Omit<Result, MutableProps>>
        : Tuple<Length, Type, [...Result, Type]>)


let person: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    hobbies: string[];
    role: Tuple<2, string>
} = {
    name: 'stack overflow',
    age: 30,
    hobbies: ['reading', 'jogging'],
    role: ['reading', 'jogging'],
};

person.role[1] = 'reader';  //ok
person.role[10] = 'reader';  // expected error
person.role.push(); //allowed, TS compiler should prevent it
person.role.sort // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N91A7N)

**Diversity tuple**

```js
type WithoutIndex<T> = Omit<T, number>

type MutableProps = 'push' | 'splice' | 'shift' | 'unshift' | 'pop' | 'sort'

type DiversityTuple<T extends readonly any[]> = WithoutIndex<Omit<T, MutableProps>>

const diffTUple: DiversityTuple<[string, number]> = ['hello', 42]

diffTUple[0] = 'a' // ok
diffTUple[1] = 1 // ok

diffTUple[10] = 1 // expected error
diffTUple[0] = 1 // expected error
diffTUple[1] = 'b' // expected error
```

Comment: Good attempt @captain-yossarian from Ukraine, just one question, will this support a Tuple which has 2 types ?
Example: `[number, string]`

Comment: @pixlboy sure, made an update